# redirecting arbitrary tcp/udp in kvm

Tags: ssh, redirect, kvm-virtualization

I've got a server with KVM on it, and multiple guest VMs. I'd like a way to redirect traffic from the host server to the VMs. Like, say, forward all traffic on port 2222 on the host to 22 on a guest VM for ssh. This would have to be done either through virt-manager or libvirt XML config files -- I've found multiple references to doing it through qemu (like http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=237969) but absolutely nothing that I can see related to either libvirt or virt-manager. Do you know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for KVM, but why not use iptables ? You can put all the redirections you want in one line :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2222 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to 192.168.153.12:22
```

Comment: Dom, about two minutes after I posted my question there I saw a lot of referrals to iptables. It's probably the Correct Way, so let me to a little bit of banging on it and I'll report back. Thanks!

Comment: Bah. No dice. Connection refused with ssh, nothing sensible with just telnetting to the port either. Uncommented #net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 in /etc/sysctl.conf too.

Comment: I forget to say that the IP at the end is the VM IP, with its port. The --dport is the listening port on KVM server. If you use sysctl.conf, don't forget to reload it by "sysctl -p"

Comment: Your VM IP are bridged or NATted on the KVM host ? If they are bridged, you have a routed problem to solved !